# Are Davis Cup matches accepted as official matches, do they appear in the players' stats?

Tags: tennis, davis-cup

Are Davis Cup matches counted as official matches for the players?

Answer (score 1):

Yes they are. The ATP World Tour shows the Davis Cup Finals in their official [Calendar of tournaments](https://www.atptour.com/en/tournaments), which links to the page [Davis Cup Finals](https://www.atptour.com/en/tournaments/davis-cup-finals/8099/overview).

It is also important to note this from [ATP Rankings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ATP_Rankings) in Wikipedia:

> Starting in 2016, points were no longer awarded for Davis Cup ties,<sup>[16](http://www.atpworldtour.com/en/rankings/rankings-faq)</sup> nor for the tennis tournament at the Summer Olympics.<sup>[17](http://www.tennisworldusa.org/news/news/ATP_Tennis/27978/itf-confirms-no-atp-points-will-be-assigned-at-olympic-games-in-rio-2016/)</sup>

Answer (score 1):

Davis Cup matches do count towards a player's official stats, head to head record.
But not all zone group matches do count.
e.g. **Group IV Africa** does not count.

---

Most of the time, by `Davis Cup` people mean `Davis Cup Finals` (`World Group` up to 2019) but it is worth knowing it's a multi-layer competition.